# Remove specific rows from dataframe when it was opened without indexes using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my xlsx file I have lines (generally starting and ending) that have hash signs at the beginning and that I would like to delete.
I thought to open the file with pandas without indexes and delete the lines that have a hash at the beginning.

This is my file (I would like to remove the red lines)
[image]

What is the best way to do this?

(edit)
After which I would like to open the file using the first row as column indexes for the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

This should work : data = pd.read_excel(filepath, header=0,  skiprows=2, skipfooter = 3)

(edited for varibale lines in the center)

Comment: the number of lines in the center is variable, how can I solve this?

Comment: edited ! i would recommend looking at the doc https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html and study the parameters it offers :)

Comment: Thanks a lot this works! Except that even in this case there is no check on the # so if they vary it no longer works. Furthermore after doing this I would need to open the dataframe using the first row as column indexes

Comment: hmmm i don't know a solution to that problem, a solution would be to read it all as a dataframe then : df = df[~df['your column'].isin(['#'])]